# How does Arduino measures voltage lower than 5v?

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

While i was making a little project with Arduino Uno, i noticed, that Arduino doesn't show me the real voltage. Because, when I checked the voltage with my multimeter, it showed me the value as i supposed, and it was different from value Arduino showed. Maybe, I did something wrong. So, i'd like to know the principle of Arduino measuring voltage.
Could anyone help me understand this? Thanks!

P.S. the voltage i measured is lower that 5v

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because "How ADC works?" is not a programming question.

Comment: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/4128/analog-reference-and-power-voltage

Comment: OP should simply read the datasheet, which answers nearly every question posted with this tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arduino compares the input voltage via GPIO pins with its own 5V DC power supply and maps the input voltage accordingly. Suppose if Arduino is given 4 volts dc power supply then its ADC will give output of 1024 to 4V input via any analog pin. So in your case your reading might be different because of your input power supply.